# Can I access a Parquet file via index without reading the entire file into memory?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I just read that HDF5 allows you to access seek into data without reading the entire file into memory.

Is this seeking behavior possible in Parquet files without Java (non-pyspark solutions)? I am using Parquet because of the strong dtype support.

```py
import h5py

f = h5py.File('my_file.hdf5', 'w')
dset = f.create_dataset('coords', data=my_ndarray)
f.close()

f = h5py.File('my_file.hdf5', 'r')
dset = f['coords']
my_array = dset[-2:]
```

> https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#inspecting-the-parquet-file-metadata

I see here that Parquet metadata has `num_row_groups: 1 (or more)`. But I am not sure how that helps me fetch rows [23, 42, 117, 99293184].

Comment: Of course, you can write metadata to a parquet file, and use that metadata to "index" a particular rowgroup which contains the data you want.

Comment: I’m a little unsure what you are after.  Are you asking in Parquet supports random access?  For example, you are not using HDF5 and you want similar capability?

Comment: Or are you asking if HDF5’s random access is good enough to support parquet’s partial read models?  For example, you are storing parquet files in an HDF5 store.

Comment: @Pace yes, i want to fetch a list of rows from parquet

Comment: Does @Pace answer your question? If so, would be good to accept the answer. If not, do leave a comment so we can improve it!

Comment: @Robino I see `pyarrow.parquet.read_table(filter)` mentions rows and partition keys but haven't tried to seek into them yet https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html

Answer (score 5):

Parquet allows some forms of partial / random access.  However, it is limited.  Each parquet file is made up of one or more row groups and each parquet file is made up of one or more columns.  You can retrieve any combination of rows groups & columns that you want.

There is only one way to store columns in a parquet file.  However, it is up to the creator of the file how to distribute the rows into row groups.  The creator could put every row in its own row group (although this would be too inefficient) or they could choose to use one row group for the entire file (this is quite common).

This means the ability to do partial reads is going to depend on how the file was created.  If you are creating the files and you know ahead of time what sorts of reads are going to be done to access the data you can use this to create row groups.  If you don't know the access patterns ahead of time or you have no control over the creation of the files you are reading then you will likely have to read the entire file into memory and filter later.

Another common scenario is to store a single large dataset across many files (so that some rows are in each file).  This allows for the same sort of partial read behavior that you would have from multiple row groups.  However, having multiple files is sometimes easier to manage.

Both pyarrow and fastparquet should give you APIs for filtering row groups.  They also expose the parquet file metadata so that you can access the metadata information yourself to implement some custom filtering mechanism.

Comment: Interesting! Can you give an example of how to read only certain rows of a very big parquet file, for example with the Pandas API or another Python API?

Comment: @Basj an entire file will always be load. what he suggested is: you have to partition your table to save to different files (row groups: each file represent only range of rows, partition by column: save different columns to different files). Then how to filter the file is your job. there is no standard way to do this. Basically you have to implement the indexing/skipping/caching by yourself.